# Zope: standard_error_message: ZSQLMethod not working

Tags: sql, error-handling, zope

In my Zope website I have customized the standard_error_message as a Python script. This script differentiates between error-types and handles redirects for NotFound-errors. For this, it accesses some ZSQLMethods without problems.

Now I wanted to log the NotFound-errors into a mySQL database (yes I know they are logged in Z2.log) and added another ZSQLMethod for this purpose.

Strangely this ZSQLMethod does not work when called from the standard_error_message script. It works (writes into the database) when called from another python script, also when this other script is called per http-request from an anonymous user. If called from standard_error_message, it throws an error if not called correctly but otherwise just does not write into the database (no error logged).

I'm really lost with this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into transaction issues.

Zope wraps all requests in a transaction, and all external database interactions are [tied into that transaction too](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/RelationalDatabases.html#transactions).

This transaction is committed when a request is handled successfully, and no exceptions were raised, and *aborted* when there *was* an exception.

The `standard_error_message` is displayed when there were exceptions; and because there was an exception, your SQL INSERT is rolled back as the transaction aborts.

You'll have to explicitly commit just the SQL transaction; add a `COMMIT` statement to your SQL method.

Comment: Thanks, that completely makes sense now :) What's the best way to use commit in a Python script? I can't import transaction right away, should I declare it public in __init__.py?

Comment: I changed my standard_error_message to an external method so I can import transation.commit. Works like a charm now.